# How to avoid UIButton backgoundImage become darker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want my button become just what I have in my background image when selected.
I have tried following code

```
[button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_button_selected1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

But it doesn't work.

I considered to use `UIControlStateHighlighted`, but I'm using the button.selected property. I don't think that effect for highlighted will work for the state selected.
How do I remove the darker effect on my button?

I create my button by

`UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Update:
I think `[button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];` Can work.

I finally used an UIView with a background color and put it under my button to finish my work.

Then I found that I accidentally changed the background color of my `viewController.view`. Then I changed it back and it works with `[button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];`

Sorry for my fault about this.

Comment: Show how you create the button

Comment: have you tried with changing control state to Normal?